# Doubts on bit-shifting behavior

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, bit-shift

I would like to clear some doubts on bit-shifting:

1. Using `unsigned int`:

   `unsigned int i = 500;`
   `i << 24;`

   As far as I know this causes `unsigned int` to overflow, is this perfectly fine?

> C++17 (8.5.7/2) - The value of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the
>   result is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type.

2. Is using right-shift on `signed int` perfectly fine as long as I am shifting less than '32 bit' because 'int' is 32 bits on my platform.

   `int i = 500;`
   `i >> 31;`

Is that an overflow?

> C++17 (8.5.7/3) The value of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has
>   an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a non-negative value,
>   the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of
>   E1/2^E2.

Comment: There is no `unsigned` overflow. When overflow would occur on an `unsigned` value, the number is reduced modulo by the largest value for type + 1. There is `signed` overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > is this perfectly fine?

   Yes. `i` will become `4093640704`, in hexadecimal `0xf4000000`.
2. > Is that an overflow?

   No. It is a right shift (division-like operation), so `i` will become zero.

Note, that the rules about shift are very likely to change. Currently, several cases are undefined behavior or implementation defined. As the next standard will require two's complement arithmetic, the rules about shifting will be relaxed: the only undefined behavior will be, if the shift amount is larger or equal than the types' width. Here are the current draft rules: [link](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift).

Comment: It's also undefined if you left-shift a negative value, or if a left-shift of a positive signed value overflows.

Comment: @interjay: do you mean, in the current draft standard? (I'm talking about the current draft there)

Comment: In C++17, does that mean right shift on *positive* `signed` integer is well-defined? I suppose left shift on *positive* 'signed` integer is not if value is not representable.

Comment: I'm talking about the last released standard, C++17 (which the question is tagged as). I don't know if things changed in the latest draft.

Comment: "in C++17, does that mean right shift on positive signed integer is well-defined?" Yes. "I suppose left shift on positive 'signed` integer is not if value is not representable." It is UB only, if the result is not representable in the unsigned version. So, shifting into the sign-bit is fine (implementation-defined), but shifting more is not. But these rules doesn't matter too much anymore, as the next draft simplified them, as it will require two's complement numbers.

Comment: @interjay: it will very likely to change, that's what I talking about, I've even put a link there. But I've expanded my note a little bit, to be more clear.

Comment: @geza: Does that mean there's no integer overflow on signed integer when right shift is used because the result wraps around? (C++17)

Comment: @user963241: I don't understand you fully. Right shift is a division-like operation. Why do you think it causes overflow? It can only decrease a value. When we say overflow, it means that a value is so large (in magnitude) that it doesn't fit into the result type.

Comment: @geza: Okay, I see, I was using this wiki definition: `an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the range that can be represented with a given number of digits – either larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.`  it includes minimum representable value as well.

Comment: @user963241: yes, but right shift always decreases (or doesn't change) a value (in magnitude). So, for example, `8>>1==4`, `-8>>1==-4` (right-shifting a negative value is implementation-defined in C++17, but not in current draft). It is not possible that a right-shift causes overflow. Think of `>>` as division, with the subtle difference that an integer division rounds towards zero, while `>>` rounds down (for positive numbers, they are the same, for negatives they can differ).